# Displaying picture in default Outlook signature using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below is code that creates emails with attachments in a specified table. I worked on keeping my default signature in these emails and noticed the image is not displayed.

This code will be used by other users so keeping it linked to the default Outlook signature would be ideal.

```vb
Sub send_Multiple_Email()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Email Table")

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object, signature As String

Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

With msg
    .Display
    signature = msg.HTMLbody
End With

Dim i As Integer
Dim last_row As Integer

last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("B:B"))

With msg

    For i = 2 To last_row
        Set msg = OA.createitem(0)
 
        msg.To = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        msg.cc = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        msg.Subject = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
        msg.HTMLbody ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 3").Text & vbNewLine & signature
        msg.Attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value

        msg.Display
    Next i 

    MsgBox "Emails Prepared"

End With

Set OA = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Everything works as expected aside from my company logo disappearing in the added signature. Drafting an email manually works but running this code does not display the picture.

Comment: Consider upvoting if an answer from these apply [Adding default signature, that consists of images, in Outlook using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654861/adding-default-signature-that-consists-of-images-in-outlook-using-excel-vba) and [Add signature with images to the Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999201/add-signature-with-images-to-the-mail)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `signature` assignment into the email creation loop:

```vb
Sub send_Multiple_Email()

  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Email Table")

  Dim OA As Object
  Dim msg As Object, signature As String

  Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

' ~> FROM THIS
'  With msg
'    .Display
'    signature = msg.HTMLbody
'  End With

  Dim i As Integer

  Dim last_row As Integer
  last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("B:B"))

  With msg
    For i = 2 To last_row
      Set msg = OA.createitem(0)
' ~> TO THIS
      msg.Display
      signature = msg.HTMLbody

      msg.To = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
      msg.cc = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
      msg.Subject = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
      msg.HTMLbody ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 3").Text & vbNewLine & signature
      msg.Attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value

    Next i

    MsgBox "Emails Prepared"

  End With

  Set OA = Nothing
  Set msg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked like a charm, I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Mark this message as answer, thank you)

Comment: For cleaner code, consider commenting the `Set msg = OA.createitem(0)` just above `' ~> FROM THIS`. Then comment `With msg` and `End With`.